How to create RestrictedDataToken to get restricted data of Direct Fulfillment Orders
I want to get buyer name and ship address of Amazon Direct Fulfillment Orders, per the instruction of getOrders of Vendor Direct Fulfillment Orders API, we need to obtain the restrictedDataToken first, but the errors happened just like the attachment.
enter image description here
I have use Postman to implement the request for restrictedDataToken API,
createRestrictedDataToken:
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/tokens-api-v2021-03-01-reference
getOrders api of Direct Fulfillment Orders:
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/vendor-direct-fulfillment-orders-api-2021-12-28-reference#getorders
